# Convert binary integer to decimal using bellow algorithm

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone please give me instruction how to write the program using this algorithm?
To convert binary integer to decimal, start from the left. Take your current total, multiply it by two and add the current digit. Continue until there are no more digits left.

First need to input the binary number as a string then select one by one digits of binary number

```
    num=input("Enter the binary integer Number: ")
    num=str(num)
    decimal=''
    rem=0
    i=0
    i=int(i)

    dig=num[i]
    dig=int(dig)
    rem=(rem*2)+dig
    i=i+1

    dig=num[i]
    dig=int(dig)
    rem=(rem*2)+dig
    i=i+1

    dig=num[i]
    dig=int(dig)
    rem=(rem*2)+dig
    i=i+1

   dig=num[i]
   dig=int(dig)
   rem=(rem*2)+dig
   i=i+1

   decimal=int(rem)
   print(decimal)
```

This code only calculate 4 digits of binary numbers. How can i add a while loop in this code?

Comment: please add your example code. or what you have tried so far.

Comment: This code only calculate 8 bit binary numbers (4-digits)
i can i use a while loop for this code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put that in a loop:

```
binary = input("Enter the binary integer Number: ")
decimal = 0
for dig in binary:
    decimal = decimal*2 + int(dig)

print(decimal)
```

Note that in Python 3, `input` already returns a string type value, so you don't need to convert it with `str()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `int()` function:

```
binary_string = input('Please input a binary number: ')
print(int(binary_string, 2))
```

A one liner, just because it is possible:

```
print(int(input('Please input a binary number: '), 2))
```

But if you really want to do this with a loop, you can do:

```
binary_string = input('Please input a binary number: ')
result = 0
multiplier = 1
for digit in binary_string[::-1]:
    result += int(digit) * multiplier
    multiplier *= 2
print(result)
```